# canvas. Unexpected ends of the line

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I need to get a picture like this:
[image: target]

```js
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(20, 20);
context.lineTo(120, 70);
context.lineTo(220, 20);
context.lineWidth = 15;
context.stroke();
context.fillStyle = 'aqua';
context.fill();
```

But as a result, I get this picture:
[image: result]

Is it possible to get rid of such unexpected ends of the line?

Comment: A stroke’s coordinates determine the _middle_ of the line, not the top. Either use math to draw the stroke using the correct coordinates or clear everything above the triangle, if possible.

Comment: @SebastianSimon It would all be oh so easy if the drawing API had a stroke offset property...

Comment: @AKX Unfortunately not easy at all no: https://svgwg.org/specs/strokes/#SpecifyingStrokeAlignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this *particular* case, you can just clear the rectangle above the triangle, as shown below.

The issue in general is that you're drawing a 15-unit-wide line centered along the triangle's edge; you'd have to compute how much to extend the line outside the triangle and halve its width, or to compute a similar filled polygon, to make this work in the general case.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(20, 20);
context.lineTo(120, 70);
context.lineTo(220, 20);
context.lineWidth = 15;
context.stroke();
context.fillStyle = 'aqua';
context.fill();
context.clearRect(10, 10, 210, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="240" height="100">
```